# Angular 6 injecting window token in library service

Tags: angular6, window-object, angular-library

I have a library that has the code from this website post:
https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/

In my library, I also have a service where I want to have access to the window object. However, adding in the following to the constructor is not working:

```
@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window
```

When trying to build the library with the cli, the following error occurs:

> Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime:
>   Could not resolve type Window.

I can change it to use the type any rather than Window, or add @dynamic as a comment and it does then build OK. Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm not sure if this is even the right way to do it, as it also relies on the consumer to have set WINDOW_PROVIDERS in its main app module providers array.

Comment: Please take a look at this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23395#issuecomment-381936725. Maybe you can use this workaround as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same service and I'm injecting it like this:

```
@Inject(WINDOW) private _window: Window
```

Notice the underscore ('_') character in front of the window variable. I suspect you cannot name a variable window, because this would clash with the built-in browser window object.
Other than that, make sure that you are importing the injection token in your component/service as such:

```
import { WINDOW } from '[path to your services]/window.service';
```

And in you `app.module.ts` (or whatever module you're using it in):

```
import { WINDOW_PROVIDERS } from '[path to your services]/window.service';
...
  providers: [
    WINDOW_PROVIDERS
  ]
...
```